# Issue in Visual Studio Code editor. Why are files closing when I save them?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, save

---

## Why are files closing when I save them?

---

When ever I create a new file, add a couple lines of code to the file, and attempt to save my work, the file immediately closes, right when I initiate the save. Furthermore, the file that closes is not appearing in the ***"Open recent"*** file list that's located in the file menu.

**Edit : The file immediately closes after I save as it, because when I click "run Python File", It open File Explorer tab**

###### *Does anyone know if this is a known issue, or if I can solve this problem by reconfiguring a* 'VS Code' *setting*?

Comment: Have you modified the shortcut? What about `File` -> `Save`?

Answer (score 0):

##### Use Directories to Save Files

It is better to open directories in **VS Code**, than it is to open a single file without a parent directory.

**`File > Open Folder or Ctrl+K Ctrl+O`**

The folder that opens, using the keybinding above, can be used to save all the files you want.

---

##### Using the Open Recent File-list:

After opening Code, the last project (or folder) will already be open. If not, just go to

If not, you should be able to just go to

**`File > Open Recent > "Folder/Project Name"`**

If you use Windows, with the right button on the folder you can click on "open with code", it will open the folder directly in Code

---

**TIP:** *"You can turn on auto-save* — *using* **`File > Auto Save`** — *to save time"*

Comment: This sounds right, please let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening to me too. In my case it turn out to be a `PHP-CS-FIXER` extension has some error which was the reason the file got closed after saving. Try to disable `PHP-CS-FIXER` extension or may be in your case it could be some other ext